# How to view the definition of a sequence?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, tsql-sequence

I want to retrieve the definition of a sequence through a query. I have already done this with triggers:

```
USE dbName 
SELECT c.text FROM sys.syscomments c 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT object_id FROM SYS.triggers WHERE name = 'triggerName'
) t ON c.id = t.object_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see information about all sequences like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sequences
```